# Expose an enumeration from a wrapped COM component

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, com, interop

I'm writing a class library in .NET that wraps a COM dll and exposes specific functionality to be consumed by other .NET code.  The COM library has several enumerations defined and I've used some of the enum types as parameters like so:

```
//C#
public void TransactionTypeSetByEnum(COMComponent.TransactionType transType)
{
    this.TransactionType = transType
}

'VB.NET'
Public Sub TransactionTypeSetByEnum( _
  ByVal transType As COMComponent.TransactionType)
    Me.TransactionType = transactionType
End Sub
```

However, when I go to consume this .NET wrapper from a different project, the compiler can't see the COM types (and I don't want to expose them to the consuming class).  For example...

```
 netWrappedObject.TransactionTypeSetByEnum( //...No intellisense for the enum
```

Is there a way to expose the underlying unmanaged enumeration in my .NET wrapper library without adding an unmanaged DLL reference the project that's responsbile for consuming that library?

---

Additional background information:

The business already has working VB6 code that has been compiled into a COM component.  The business does not want to rewrite those components in .NET managed code, but wants to be able to consume that existing code in a .NET application.  Rather than have every .NET application pull the COM component in directly, my goal is to write a .NET "wrapper" around the existing COM component and expose needed functionality with classes and interfaces to other .NET application.

Part of my thinking behind using interface design to wrap the COM dll is this: should the business decide later on that it would be better to rewrite the existing COM dll to be 100% managed .NET code, all I would have to do is implement the interface with the new code and change the existing applications to reference the new assembly and possibly change one line of code.  This avoids the need to have to rewrite the implementation of the COM dll for each .NET application.

In my question above, my problem is that the COM dll has several `enum`s that I want to be exposed *through* the .NET component that "wraps" that DLL.  Let's say the COM dll has a class called `ComFoo` which has an enumeration call `ComFooEnum`.  I want the `NetFoo` class to somehow expose `ComFooEnum` when other projects consume `NetFoo`.  I don't want the other projects to be required to reference `ComFoo` just to be able to see the `enum` exposed by `NetFoo`.  If I have to mimic `ComFooEnum` and make a new `NetFooEnum`, I suppose that's what I'll do, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Here's a diagram that tries to explain the encapsulation I'm trying to achieve:

```
______________________________  
|                            |  
| Compiled VB6 COM Assembly  |  
|  Exposes class called      |  
|     ComFoo                 |  
|____________________________|   
                        ||
_____________________   ||
|                   |   ||
| Existing VB6      |   ||
| Business          |  < |
| Application       |   ||
| references ComFoo |
|___________________|

//The business is building new applications in .NET
//that need to consume ComFoo, which cannot be rewritten.
//NetFoo exposes the functionality of ComFoo.

____________________________________
|                                  |
|        .NET Wrapper Assembly     |
|    Exposes class called NetFoo   |
|  ______________________________  |
|  |                            |  |
|  | Compiled VB6 COM Assembly  |  |
|  |  Exposes class called      |  |
|  |     ComFoo                 |  |
|  |____________________________|  |
|__________________________________|
                        ||
_____________________   ||
|                   |   ||
| New .NET Business |  < |
|  Order Entry App  |   ||
| references NetFoo |   ||
|___________________|   ||
                        ||
_____________________   ||
|                   |   ||
| New .NET Business |   ||
|  Internet App     |  < |
| references NetFoo |   ||
|___________________|
```

Comment: What have you made `<ComVisible>`?  This is an IDE issue, not a compiler issue.  What IDE?

Comment: @Hans  I'm using VS2010. I'm not sure that I need to use <ComVisible>. I'm trying to get the wrapped COM component types to be visible to other .NET projects, not to COM. What will <ComVisible> gain me?

Comment: I don't have a clue why you'd want to make a ComVisible component visible to a .NET program.  I suspect you've been doing COM for, perhaps, too long, I've posted an answer to many of your COM questions.  It makes no sense at all to create a ComVisible .NET component and use it in a .NET program as a COM component.  Just use the assembly directly without jumping through the COM hoop.  Not sure at all if I'm on the right track with this, going off your question title.

Comment: @Hans I'm not sure that we're understanding the problem in the same way.  I've updated my question to try to provide more background information.  To answer your other points: It's not that *I* have been doing COM for too long (I actually just began doing software professionally only 6 months ago), but rather that the business I work for is very comfortable in the world of COM.  I'm trying to get the business to look at using .NET more frequently and that's where all of the COM interop issues come in. I really appreciate your feedback and taking the time to look at my questions.

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic available here.  Just as you wrap the interface types from the COM component with equivalent .NET types, so you have to wrap other declarations from the type library.  If you don't want to expose the COM enum types then you have to wrap them.  With a .NET enum type declaration.  The code is simple by casting through int, but it is a maintenance item.  Just like the .NET class wrappers are.  Make sure there's an actual value-add from wrapping the COM types, a one-to-one mapping is rarely useful.

Unless this is training wheels for an eventual replacement of the COM server.  Which is a-okay, it gives you a good feel for what's needed.  In which case you really *do* want to declare the enum.

Comment: +1 I don't understand the benefit of the .Net wrapper. To me the obvious upgrade path would be to replace the COM component with a.Net one with equivalent signature. That component could be used for all the .Net clients. Sounds like this is a refactoring in order to make possible future changes easier . But what is to be gained by doing it now, not during the future change? I don't understand the benefit in this case.